# plsql - xml data reference through cursor

Tags: xml, plsql

I have a package and need to output the XML data through the cursor. I never worked on Xml data. Please let me know whatever you understand from the below package and xml

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY  PK_FCP_EXTRACT is

PROCEDURE sp_fcp_extract is

     cursor Rev_cur is select * from t_uar_reviews where CREATED_DATE=trunc(sysdate) ;
       r Rev_cur%rowtype;
      cursor case_cur( c_revid IN t_uar_reviews.uar_review_id%type )
          is select *
               from t_uar_cases where uar_review_id= c_revid ;
     c case_cur%rowtype;
   begin
    open Rev_cur;
    loop
       fetch Rev_cur into r;
       exit when Rev_cur%notfound;
       open case_cur( r.uar_review_id );
       loop
         fetch case_cur into c;
         exit when case_cur%notfound;
         dbms_output.put_line(c.UAR_CASE_ID||','||c.UAR_REVIEW_ID||','||c.CASE_TYPE||','||c.CASE_NMBR||','||c.ACTIVE_FLAG||','|| c.CREATED_DATE);

---dbms_output.put_line (XML string) ; #please tel me how to use 

       end loop;
       close case_cur;
     end loop;
     close Rev_cur;
  end;

END PK_FCP_EXTRACT;
```

this is the XML data

```
        vXML_Msg := to_clob('<BUSINESS_INDICATOR_ID>1</BUSINESS_INDICATOR_ID > ' ||
                 '<RECEIVED_DATE>' ||to_char(sysdate,'yyyy-mm-ddTmm:ss:00')|| '</RECEIVED_DATE>' ||
                 '<ZONE_ID>1</ZONE_ID>' ||
                 '<ORIGINATOR_LAN_ID>' || t_uar_reviews.REVIEWED_BY || '</ORIGINATOR_LAN_ID> ' ||
                 '<ORIGINATOR_AU>0070705</ORIGINATOR_AU>' ||
                 '<EVENT_DESCRIPTION>' || t_uar_reviews.SUMMARY_NOTE || '</EVENT_DESCRIPTION> ' ||
                 '<FRAUD_POTENTIAL_LOSS_AMOUNT>' ||sum(t_uar_cases.exposure_amt) || '</FRAUD_POTENTIAL_LOSS_AMOUNT> '||
                 '<ALERT_ID>' ||t_uar_reviews.UAR_REVIEW_ID || '</ALERT_ID>' ||
                 '<CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID>' || wells.t_hogan_acct_cust_month.ssn_taxid_ind || '</CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID> ' ||
                 '<ENTERPRISE_CUSTOMER_NUMBER>' || t_uar_cases.ecn ||'</ENTERPRISE_CUSTOMER_NUMBER> '||
                 '<TAX_ID_NUMBER>' || t_uar_cases.tax_id ||'</TAX_ID_NUMBER> ' ||
                 '<ACCOUNT_NUMBER>' || t_uar_cases.acct_nmbr ||'</ACCOUNT_NUMBER>' ||
                 '<ACCOUNT_COMPANY_NUMBER>' || wells.t_hogan_acct_cust_xref.coid || '</ACCOUNT_COMPANY_NUMBER>' ||
                 '<ACCOUNT_PRODUCT_CODE>' || wells.t_hogan_acct_cust_xref.cis_prod ||'</ACCOUNT_PRODUCT_CODE>' ||
                 '<EVENT_UAR_FRAUD_ATTACHMENT>' || wells.t_file_attachment ||'</EVENT_UAR_FRAUD_ATTACHMENT>' ||
                 '<FILE_NAME>' ||wells.t_file_attachment||'</FILE_NAME>' ||
                 '<DISPOSITON_STATUS_NAME>' || uar.t_disposition.disposition_desc || '</DISPOSITON_STATUS_NAME>' ||
                 '<CASE_TYPE_NAME>' || t_uar_cases.case_type ||'</CASE_TYPE_NAME>' ||
                 '<CASE_NUMBER>' || t_uar_cases.case_nmbr||'</CASE_NUMBER>' ||
                 '<FRAUD_POTENTIAL_LOSS_AMOUNT>' || t_uar_cases.exposure_amt ||'</FRAUD_POTENTIAL_LOSS_AMOUNT>' ||
                 '<LAST_COMPANY_NAME>' || t_uar_cases.full_name||'</LAST_COMPANY_NAME>' ||
                 '<CASE_OPEN_DATE>' || t_uar_cases.created_date ||'</CASE_OPEN_DATE>' ||
                 '<CASE_CLOSE_DATE>' || t_uar_cases.close_date ||'</CASE_CLOSE_DATE>' ||
                 '<CRIME_RING_ID>' || t_uar_cases.ring_id ||'</CRIME_RING_ID>' ||
                 '<CRIME_RING_NAME>' || t_uar_cases.ring_name ||'</CRIME_RING_NAME>' ||
                 '<SOR_PARENT_CASE_ID>' || t_uar_cases.uar_case_id ||'</SOR_PARENT_CASE_ID>' )
```

this should be used in dbms_output.put_line in the above procedure.

Comment: So you need to create a XML while looping cursors?

Comment: @ErgiNushi - The data should reference through the cursors.

Comment: @ErgiNushi- I have edited my Question. The XML string should be the output by using dbms_output.put_line

Comment: Check Oracle docs: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb13gen.htm#ADXDB4994